# Every normal matrix is diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra

Sorry, I mis-typed the question. The real question is that
Every normal matrix is diagonalizable?
and the answer is False.
Can you give me a counter example?

Comment: F is obviously the field. The matrices have entries from F. R is obviously the reals. @user1551

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let 
$$A=\left(\begin{matrix}1&i\\
i&-1\end{matrix}\right)$$
then $A$ is a symmetric complex matrix and its characteristic polynomial
$$\chi_A(x)=\det(A-xI)=x^2$$
then if $A$ is diagonalizable then it's similar to the zero matrix which is clearly false.

**Added** A complex matrix $A$ is normal if $AA^*=A^*A$ and this matrix is diagonalizable. see [Normal matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix)

Comment: The matrix you proposed is not self-adjoint, it is symmetric. This is not the same for complex matrices.

Comment: I think that the OP means a symmetric complex matrix since a self-adjoint matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: I agree. My comment was mainly for the OP, who might have understood your answer in the wrong way!

Comment: Sorry, I mis-type the question so I corrected it. But I choose your answer, thanks. For the others who confused with this, my original question was "every self-adjoint matrix is diagonalizable?" and this is the answer for that.

Comment: @gma. you're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Every normal matrix $A$, $A^\dagger A=A A^\dagger$, is diagonalizable with unitary matrix:

$A=U^\dagger D U$

where $U$ is unitary and $D$ is diagonal, superscript $\dagger$ denotes Hermitian transpose. In fact checking that a matrix is normal is a common diagonalizability test.